# Convert $_Files['userfile']['name'] to variable

Tags: php, post

I am using code for an to upload files as seen below:

```
$uploaddir = "./images/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}
```

The code works to upload the image but I want to be able to post the filename to an SQL database afterwords.

I need to get the filename I uploaded and make it a variable called `$filename` so i can then use:

```
$image = $_POST[$filename];
```

I've tried using this to make it a variable

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

All I get is an error saying undefined index : image.jpg on the `$_POST` and I'm uncertain why. Its listing the image filename in the error so why cant it upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access `$_POST[$filename]` if you're posting an input with the name "image.jpg", which I guess you aren't.

You've already got the filename from the $_FILES array, so why not use it again?

```
$image = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

... or use the `$filename` variable that you've already got (can't see where this is defined in your example, but it obviously contains "image.jpg")

**Note:** the `name` part of `$_FILES['input_name']` arrays contains the **original filename** of the uploaded file. That's all you need.

Comment: ive added how i will use $image as im not really certain how to take your suggestions and thought it may help

Comment: Don't use the $_POST array at all, just use `$filename`

Comment: but don't i need the $_POST otherwise when i ran the sql i wouldn't be able to send it to my database without it

Comment: **A.** it doesn't look like you're posting anything. **B.** it doesn't matter where your variables come from, if you've got what you want (image.jpg) then use it.

Comment: yeah now i get it i had a post for the other things i was sending to the database so was assuming i was needing it again. i removed the post and just used $filename as the value and its working. I was just overcomplicating it. Thanks for the help